# How do I call a class method that returns a class method pointer?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

This compiles fine, but gives me a linker error "undefined reference to A::a(std::string const&)"

How do I correctly call A::a(const std::string& name) and how do I correctly call funcTable.second() in my doSomething() method?

.h file:

```
class A {
    void (A::*a(const std::string& name))() const;
    void func1() const;
    void func2() const;
    void doSomething();
};
```

.cpp file:

```
void (A::*a(const std::string& name))() const {
    const std::map<const std::string, void (A::*)() const> funcMap = {
        {"name1", &A::func1},
        {"name2", &A::func2}
    };
    return funcMap.at(name);
}
void A::func1() const {
    // call func1
}
void A::func2() const {
    // call func2
}
void A::doSomething() {
    std::pair<std::string, void (A::*)() const> funcTable;
    funcTable.first = "func1";
    funcTable.second = a("name1");    // This is my problem
    // Not even sure how to then call funcTable.second()
}
```

I realize a typedef would make this a lot cleaner. I tried this approach, but I'm not sure how to do that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void (A::*a(const std::string& name))() const {
```

This is not defining your class method. This is defining a standalone function in the global namespace, which returns a class method pointer. What you want is:

```
void (A::*A::a(const std::string& name))() const {
```

This defines a class method that returns a pointer to a class member. Quite a mouthful.

> I realize a typedef would make this a lot cleaner.

Yes, it would. Use of typedefs is very much encouraged. Makes it possible to keep more of one's remaining sanity. Which is always a good thing.

P.S. -- if you actually tried to compile the exact code you showed in your question, it would not "compile fine", despite your assertion otherwise. You would've received the following compilation error, which gives a big honking clue as to what's going on:

```
t.C: In function ‘void (A::* a(const string&))() const’:
t.C:13:23: error: ‘void A::func1() const’ is private within this context
         {"name1", &A::func1},
```

Huh? Why is a class method unable to reference another private class method? Oh!

Comment: That did it, thank you!
I had my `void func1() const` public, so I wasn't encountering this problem, but you're absolutely correct - making them private gave me that error.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative, I suggest, instead of that ugly syntax, to use trailing return type:

```
auto A::a(const std::string& name) -> void (A::*)() const { /* implementation */ }
```

> `funcTable.second = a("name1");    // This is my problem`
>       `// Not even sure how to then call funcTable.second()`

it would be something like:

```
(instance.*funcTable.second)();
```

or

```
(this->*funcTable.second)();
```

Comment: That is so slick! That's so much clearer - thank you.